# Can I write middleware to affect the data that is being sent to my template renderer?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm writing a web application based on Node.js and Express, using Dust for my templates. My Dust templates all use the same master layout in a separate file. Right now a simple route handler in my app looks like this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        tenant: req.tenant
    });        
});
```

The tenant is being used for rendering some parts of the master layout. Now, I feel like it's pretty inefficient (devtime-wise) to add the 'tenant' variable to the view model in every route handler. In ASP.NET MVC I would write an action filter that runs after every action and adds the tenant to the view model. Is there something similar I can do in Express? Write some connect or router middleware? Or does res.render perform the rendering immediately without any possibility to modify the view model lateron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And two minutes after posting the message, a nice chap on IRC gives me the answer.

```
res.locals.tenant = <tenant>
```

in the middleware does the job.