# In Express, can I automatically include the request object as a local for all rendered templates?

Tags: node.js, express

I’ve just started learning [Express](http://expressjs.com/). I’m finding that in my templates, I often want to use properties of the request object from my route handler. For example:

#### app.js

```
...
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.render('home.swig', {
        "req": req
    });
});
...
```

#### home.swig

```
...
{% if req.user %}

<p>You’re logged in!</p>

{% else %}

<p>You’re not logged in.</p>

<p><a href="/login">Log in here</a></p>

{% endif %}
```

Is there any way I can automatically include the request object as a local in all my `res.render` calls, instead of specifying it explicitly in each one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passport.js - passing {user: req.user} to template implicitly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912283/passport-js-passing-user-req-user-to-template-implicitly)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601627/can-i-write-middleware-to-affect-the-data-that-is-being-sent-to-my-template-rend

Comment: Crikey, even the Express docs already cover this: http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals. Good research Paul!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a small piece of middleware to do this.  It would look something like:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.req = req;
    next();
});
```